# JQuery adding class to cloned element

Tags: jquery, clone, addclass

This is my script:

```
$('.addprop').click(function() {
        $('#clone').clone().insertAfter('.addprop');
    })
```

I need to add a class to the new element that is being created. Is it possible?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, it is:

```
$('.addprop').click(function() {
        $('#clone').clone().addClass('newClass').insertAfter('.addprop');
    })
```

Although you're cloning an element based on its `id`, `$('#clone')`, so note that there will be two elements sharing the ***same `id`***, which makes the result invalid HTML, so I'd suggest:

```
$('.addprop').click(function() {
        $('#clone').clone().attr('id',id += 1).addClass('newClass').insertAfter('.addprop');
    });
```

This will effectively add the number `1` to the end of the end of the current `id` value. To make this more dynamic you'd probably need to base it on a count of the number of elements of the new class-name:

```
$('.addprop').click(function() {
        $('#clone').clone().attr('id',id += $('.newClass').length).addClass('newClass').insertAfter('.addprop');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

After the `.clone()` method the *current* element is the clone..

```
$('#clone').clone().addClass('class-name-here').insertAfter('.addprop');
```

---

***Notice***

you will need to change the `id` of the clone as it must be unique in the DOM and when you clone that element, the id is cloned as well..

So better to do something like

```
$('#clone').clone().attr('id','newid').addClass('class-name-here').insertAfter('.addprop');
```