# How to create a jQuery click handler based on a matching pattern?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple reason codes (For ex: RC1, RC2...). For each of these reason codes, I want to give the user a text box in which they can enter some comments. Also give them the option of adding multiple text boxes for each reason code.

To allow the user to add a dynamic text box, I have a button which allows the user to do so. If there was only one reason code, I can easily just just append a text box to the pre-existing text box using jquery (Using something like this: [JQuery adding class to cloned element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720432/jquery-adding-class-to-cloned-element)).

However since I have multiple reason codes(over 200) it doesnt make sense of having button for each reason code in Jquery. Is there a way for me to search by a basic identifier.

I have pasted the contents of the HTML file generated by my JSP file.

```
<div id="Reasoncode1">
  <div id="inputTextBox_Reasoncode1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add some text"/><button class="button_Reasoncode1">
   +</button>
  </div>   
</div>

<p>
Reason code2
</p>
<div id="Reasoncode2">
  <div id="inputTextBox_Reasoncode2">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Add some text"/><button class="button_Reasoncode2">
   +</button>
  </div>   
</div>
```

My Jquery attempt is:

```
$(".button_Reasoncode1").click(function() {
     $('#Reasoncode1').clone().insertAfter('#inputTextBox_Reasoncode1');
});

$(".button_Reasoncode2").click(function() {
     $('#Reasoncode2').clone().insertAfter('#inputTextBox_Reasoncode2');
});
```

I dont want to do this for each and every reason code, i was wondering if there is a better approach to this. 
My JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mvp71L61/

Comment: You can store functions in an array and then run a loop to assign each array item to a particular event handler.

Comment: That would mean I will need to create about 200 functions and if I create a new reason code I will need to add that as well. Is there a way where the click handler matches the pattern "button_" & inside that function I can retrieve which reasoncode it clicked?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. You could run a "containing" selector (`[id^="Reasoncode"]`) and pass a reference to the element into the handler.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mvp71L61/1/

Comment: @Pyromonk Thanks. That helps I think. I know why the text boxes keep doubling each time, but I wasn't able to figure how to stop that.

Comment: So what exactly was the problem? I apologise if I misunderstood it yet again.

Comment: When you click the plus button, number of text boxes keep doubling

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all buttons are statically added to the DOM,

```
$("button[class*='button_Reasoncode']").click(function() {
  var rCode = $(this).attr('class').match(/\d+/g)[0]; 
  $("div[id='Reasoncode'+rcode]").clone().insertAfter("input[id='inputTextBox_Reasoncode'+rcode]");
});
```